# Cusparse illegal memory access unless I increase the sparsity of the sparse matrix

Tags: c++, cuda, sparse-matrix

I am trying to make an existing piece of software that uses hand tuned sparse multiplication of special CSC matrices that have exactly k nonzero elements per column. I decided to use cusparse for the job, but unfortunately I encounter that the matrix multiplication takes over 7 seconds in some cases, which is much slower than the CPU version of the code. (largest sparse matrix concerned is 19871x1000 largest dense matrix concerned is 1000*150, nnz = 101000).

When trying to reproduce the problem in a self contained example, I always encounter an "illegal memory access error" when nnz != sparse_cols.

After some investigation turns out that if I increase the size of matrices 10fold the problem disappears. If I make the matrices small enough I don't experience crashes. However with large matrices the sparse matrix has to not cross over some degree of denseness, otherwise multiplication produces a bunch of illegal memory accesses.
 Here is the code that exibits the problem:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cusparse.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> 

#define CALL_CUDA( err ) \
{ if (err != cudaSuccess) \
    {std::cout<<"cuda Error "<< cudaGetErrorString(err)<<" in "<<__FILE__<<" at line "<<__LINE__<<"\n"; exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }\
}


int main(){

    //cusparse status and handle
    cusparseStatus_t status; 
    cusparseHandle_t handle = 0;
    status = cusparseCreate(&handle);

    if (status != CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS){
        std::cout << "Error creating handle: " << status << std::endl;
    }

    //Set matrix description
    cusparseMatDescr_t descr; //Describe the matrices
    cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descr);
    cusparseSetMatType(descr, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL);
    cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descr, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO);

    //Sparse matrix properties
    int sparse_rows = 19871;
    int sparse_cols = 1000;
    int nnz_new = 101000;
    //int nnz_new = 1000; //Works with that value

    //Dense matrix properties
    int bmat_rows = 1000;
    int bmat_cols = 150;


    //Generate a special type of sparse matrix that has exactly k nonzero elements in each column in CSC format
    float * amat_vals;
    CALL_CUDA(cudaMallocHost((void **)&amat_vals, nnz_new*sizeof(float)));
    int * amat_idx;
    CALL_CUDA(cudaMallocHost((void **)&amat_idx, nnz_new*sizeof(int)));
    int * crccolptr;
    CALL_CUDA(cudaMallocHost((void **)&crccolptr, (sparse_cols+1)*sizeof(int)));

    //Fill in values with random values
    for (int i = 0; i < nnz_new; i++){
        amat_vals[i] = (float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
    }

    //Generate indexes for those rows
    for (int i = 0; i < nnz_new; i++){
        amat_idx[i] = rand() % (sparse_rows - 1);
    }

    //generate crccolptr
    int k = (int)(nnz_new/sparse_cols); //Number of elements per row
    for (int i = 0; i < sparse_cols; i++){
        crccolptr[i] = k*i;
    }
        crccolptr[sparse_cols] = nnz_new;


    //Generate bmat_array with random floats
    float * bmat_array;
    CALL_CUDA(cudaMallocHost((void **)&bmat_array, bmat_rows*bmat_cols*sizeof(float))); 
    for (int i = 0; i < bmat_rows*bmat_cols; i++){
        bmat_array[i] = (float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
    }

    //generate array for output
    float * outmatrix_test;
    CALL_CUDA(cudaMallocHost((void **)&outmatrix_test, sparse_rows*bmat_cols*sizeof(float)));

    //Allocate and copy device memory for sparse matrix
    float * cudavals;
    int * colIdx;
    int * colPtr;

    CALL_CUDA(cudaMalloc((void **)&colPtr, (sparse_cols + 1)*sizeof(int)));
    CALL_CUDA(cudaMemcpy(colPtr, crccolptr, (sparse_cols + 1)*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    CALL_CUDA(cudaMalloc((void **)&cudavals, nnz_new*sizeof(float)));
    CALL_CUDA(cudaMalloc((void **)&colIdx, nnz_new*sizeof(int)));

    CALL_CUDA(cudaMemcpy(cudavals, amat_vals, nnz_new*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    CALL_CUDA(cudaMemcpy(colIdx, amat_idx, nnz_new*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    //Allocate and copy device memory for dense matrix
    float * B_gpumatrix;
    CALL_CUDA(cudaMalloc((void **)&B_gpumatrix, bmat_rows*bmat_cols*sizeof(float)));
    CALL_CUDA(cudaMemcpy(B_gpumatrix, bmat_array, bmat_rows*bmat_cols*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    //Allocate output matrix
    float * outmatrix_gpu; 
    CALL_CUDA(cudaMalloc((void **)&outmatrix_gpu, (sparse_rows*bmat_cols)*sizeof(float)));

    //sparse_cols is passed as sparse_rows, because we're multiplying a CSC matrix instead of a CSR so we need
    // to transpose it and invert the rows and columns.
    const float alpha = 1.0;
    const float beta = 0.0;

/*
    float * outmatrix_gpu2; 
    CALL_CUDA(cudaMalloc((void **)&outmatrix_gpu2, (sparse_rows*sparse_cols)*sizeof(float)));
    cusparseStatus_t mat_mul = cusparseScsc2dense(handle, sparse_rows, sparse_cols, descr, cudavals, colIdx, colPtr, outmatrix_gpu2, sparse_rows);
    float * outmatrix_test2;
    CALL_CUDA(cudaMallocHost((void **)&outmatrix_test2, sparse_rows*sparse_cols*sizeof(float)));
    CALL_CUDA(cudaMemcpy(outmatrix_test2, outmatrix_gpu2, (sparse_rows*sparse_cols)*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
*/
    cusparseStatus_t mat_mul = cusparseScsrmm(handle,  //Cusparse handle
     CUSPARSE_OPERATION_TRANSPOSE, //Transposing the matrix
     sparse_cols, //Number of sparse rows. Since we're using CSC matrix it's the columns.
     bmat_cols,   //Number of columns of the dense matrix
     sparse_rows, //Number of sparse cols, Since we're using CSC matrix it's the rows
     nnz_new,     //Non zero elements
     &alpha,      //Pointer to alpha (1.0)
     descr,       //Description of the matrix
     cudavals,    //The values vector
     colPtr,      //The column pointer
     colIdx,      //The indexes of the sparse matrix
     B_gpumatrix, //Dense matrix array
     bmat_rows,   //ldb - the rows of the dense matrix
     &beta,       //Pointer to beta. It's 0
     outmatrix_gpu, //Pointer to the output matrix
     sparse_rows); //ldc - leading dimensions of the output matrix.

    if (mat_mul != CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS){
        std::cout << "MULTIPLICATION ERROR: " << mat_mul << std::endl;
    }
    cudaThreadSynchronize(); //Syncs before copy back to memory should not be necessary
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    //Copy matrix back to host
    CALL_CUDA(cudaMemcpy(outmatrix_test, outmatrix_gpu, (sparse_rows*bmat_cols)*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    CALL_CUDA(cudaFree(outmatrix_gpu));
    CALL_CUDA(cudaFree(cudavals));
    CALL_CUDA(cudaFree(colPtr));
    CALL_CUDA(cudaFree(colIdx));
    CALL_CUDA(cudaFree(B_gpumatrix));
    CALL_CUDA(cudaFreeHost(crccolptr));
    CALL_CUDA(cudaFreeHost(amat_vals));
    CALL_CUDA(cudaFreeHost(amat_idx));
    CALL_CUDA(cudaFreeHost(bmat_array));
    CALL_CUDA(cudaFreeHost(outmatrix_test));

    return 1;
}
```

I believe i am generating a valid sparse matrix, because I can convert it to dense one using the appropariate cusparse function without triggering any invalid memory accesses.

When running the above code under cuda-memcheck you can see many illegal accesses from within the cusparseScsrmm. Running without cuda-memcheck you would see an error in the first cuda operation after the matrix multiplication.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I hope that if I can solve this problem, I would be able to diagnoze (or at least isolate) a self contained example that exhibits the painfully slow matrix multiplications.

EDIT:

Using smaller matrices I don't experience the problem. sparse matrix with 50*200 works fine for NNZ until about 1000, but takes forever with NNZ = 5000 (I killed it after half a minute). Increasing matrix size to 200*500 works performs instantaneously with NNZ = 5000.... Strange.

EDIT2:

The original number of nnz works if I increase the size of the matrices 10fold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't sensible:

```
//Generate indexes for those rows
for (int i = 0; i < nnz_new; i++){
    amat_idx[i] = rand() % (sparse_rows - 1);
}
```

[CSR matrix format expects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_.28CSR_or_CRS.29) the values vector to be stored in left-to-right, top-to-bottom order.  Therefore the column indices in each row must be in *increasing order*.  You are generating column indices in random order, and in fact it's remotely possible that you will generate two elements in the same row *with the same column index*.  That is simply broken.

Your variable naming also suggests some confusion to me.  CSR is compressed sparse row format, and it expects:

1. a vector of matrix values (=nnz in length)
2. a vector of *column indices* specifying which column each value belongs to (=nnz in length)
3. a vector of *row pointers* specifying the start of each row (=numrows +1 in length)

Since you are using the `Scsrmm` function, CSR format is *required*.

variable names like `crccolptr` don't make sense to me in a CSR format.

as a simple proof-point, replace the above excerpted code with the following:

```
//Generate indexes for those rows
int my_idx = 0;
int j;
for (int i = 0; i < sparse_rows; i++){
    //amat_idx[i] = rand() % (sparse_rows - 1);
    for (j = 0; j < (nnz_new/sparse_rows); j++)
      amat_idx[my_idx++] = j;

}
while (my_idx < nnz_new) amat_idx[my_idx++] = j++;
```

And I believe the errors will go away, since the actual matrix now conforms to CSR format expectations.

Comment: I'm trying to multiply a CSC matrix with cusparse. Cusparse doesn't support CSC matrix multiplication hence in order to do that you pass CSC format "inverted" to the Scsrmm function. More can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15308625/why-cusparse-does-not-have-a-cusparsetcscmm

Comment: You are correct that the problems disappear after my matrix comforms to the CRS format, thank you for pointing that out. I suspect that the application that I am working on has the same problem since they too use CSC-like matrices and before your answer I didn't realize that the ColPtr is not directly translatable to a rowPtr. I will have to figure out how to do that translation properly

Comment: If you want, cusparse provides [a function](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#cusparse-lt-t-gt-csr2csc) that will convert a valid CSC matrix to a valid CSR matrix.  Note in the description: "Notice that this routine can also be used to convert a matrix in CSC format into a matrix in CSR format."